# obfuscating my html source from snapbuilder.com. is it reliable?

Tags: html, obfuscation

While I was searching a website that helps me to obfuscate my html source.

I found this website.

http://snapbuilder.com/code_snippet_generator/obfuscate_html_source_code/

Do you guys think this website is reliable?
I am now learning about front-end stuff, so I am not sure this helper might have some harmful code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this, it will simply make your site slow, and if they have Javascript disabled your site will not function at all. Not to mention the fact that as soon as this script is executed they will still be able to see the HTML via the dev tools in any browser.

tl;dr **DO NOT DO THIS**

Comment: Thank you for your comment!